# Unmarshalling, xml to java, invalid enum values are getting ignored that are not defined in XSD

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, unmarshalling

My `XSD` file defines only 5 types :

```
<xs:simpleType name="Types">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="TypeA" />
            <xs:enumeration value="TypeB" />
            <xs:enumeration value="TypeC" />
            <xs:enumeration value="TypeD" />
            <xs:enumeration value="TypeE" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

But say a user sends a '`TypeF`',which is not a valid type, then `unmarshalling` ,using jaxb ,is completely ignoring that value, I want to validate this value and send user a bad request exception. 
How can I make sure that if user puts an invalid Type in the `XML` , it is not ignored ?

Comment: I don't think the JAXB has anything to do with this. It simply takes the XML and does the unmarshalling. You have to do the validation yourself.

Comment: It is the jaxb apis that do unmarshalling, so there it is ignoring invalid values , instead of any errors

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an instance of `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` and return false on the `handleEvent` method to make JAXB fail on the invalid value.

Comment: @VineetSingla can you? If you post the code that you used, maybe someone would take the time to add something to it. But I doubt people want to create the entire java code to parse using JAXB for you, especially since that wasn't your question.